# How to abort XMLHttpRequest if the connection timeout?

Tags: javascript, timeout, xmlhttprequest

I'm experiencing an issue with XMLHttpRequest. If there is no Internet connection, my request is not timing out and thus freezing the browser. Here is the request code:

```
 var jsonData = new XMLHttpRequest();
 jsonData.open('GET', urltest, false);
 jsonData.Timeout = 100;
 jsonData.send(null);
 if(jsonData.status == 200) {
     alert(jsonData.statusText);
 }else{
     alert(jsonData.statusText);
 }
```

How do I abort the request if the server doesn't respond?

Comment: See: [How to detect timeout on an AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) call in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018705/how-to-detect-timeout-on-an-ajax-xmlhttprequest-call-in-the-browser)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very helpful. The main issues is that I was using synchronous HttpRequest. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, and I left some comments where I made changes explaining what's going on. I hope it helps!

```js
var jsonData = new XMLHttpRequest();
jsonData.open('GET', urltest);/* I removed the false, because it kept the browser
waiting for the page to load to continue, and it didn't let it do other things
while it was still loading.*/
jsonData.Timeout = 100;
jsonData.send();
jsonData.onreadystatechange = function() {/*Each time readyState changes value,
                                            run this code.*/
    if (jsonData.readyState == 4) {/*When readyState is equal to 4,
                     the page has fully loaded.
                     Only run the code when it's 4,
                     not when it's still loading.*/
        if (jsonData.status == 200) {
            alert(jsonData.statusText);
        } else {
            alert(jsonData.statusText);
        }
        // More things to do when the page has fully loaded...
    }
}
```

Comment: timeout with a capital letter at first instead of small one?