# Is there ever a good reason to pass a string to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

We all know that passing a string to `setTimeout` (or `setInterval`) is evil, because it is run in the global scope, has performance issues, is potentially insecure if you're injecting any parameters, etc.  So doing this is definitely deprecated:

```
setTimeout('doSomething(someVar)', 10000);
```

in favour of this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething(someVar);
}, 10000);
```

My question is: can there ever be a reason to do the former? Is it *ever* preferable? If it isn't, why is it even allowed?

The only scenario I've thought of is of wanting to use a function or variable that exists in the global scope but has been  overridden in the local scope.  That sounds to me like poor code design, however...

Comment: Based on [MDC's documention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) it seems that passing strings was the only option at the beginning (at least in Firefox). I can imagine they don't restrict passing strings to not brake compatibility... couldn't find much else for *why* (yet).

Comment: @Felix: Indeed, I was looking for that part in the docs, too. Interesting that an obvious spelling mistake actually makes your statement even more valid (‘brake’ should be ‘break’). ;-)

Comment: "If it isn't, why is it even allowed?" - this is definitely not the only thing in JavaScript that is never useful and evil, yet allowed...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always use global variables by accessing them as properties of the window object, like `window.globalVar` (though using globals is indeed not a good practice), so no, I don't think there is ever a good reason to use the deprecated syntax.

It is probably allowed for historical reasons: as Felix Kling mentioned, the original syntax did only allow to pass a string of code:

> Introduced with JavaScript 1.0, Netscape 2.0. **Passing a Function object reference was introduced with JavaScript 1.2, Netscape 4.0**; supported by the MSHTML DOM since version 5.0. [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), my emphasis]

If browsers don't support the use of a string as first argument to `setTimeout` and `setInterval` anymore, there will be lots of code on the internet that doesn't function anymore.

Comment: Judging from the amount of examples on SO that use strings ... this is unfortunately very true.

Comment: @472084 Yeah, and cancer should be cured.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are redirected here by the question of *why is passing a function better than passing a string*.

**1: Passing a string fires up a compiler**

Every time you have to evaluate a string, you fire up a full compiler.  For each and every invocation where it is needed.

Not only is this slow, it destroys all of the JIT and browser speedups that are done.

**2:  Passing a string is MUCH more limited.**

Because a string is run through a compiler, it isn't as cleanly bound to the local scope and variables.

While it isn't noticeable in situation like:

```
window.setInterval("doThing()");
```

In a more complex situation, the code is just cleaner:

```
window.setInterval("doThing(" + val1 + "," + val2 + ")");
```

vs

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  // You can put a debugging point here
  dothing(val1, val2);
});
```

**3:  DOM objects can't be passed via string**

As Álvaro mentioned, DOM objects can not be passed via a string method.

```
// There is no way to do this via a string.
var el = document.getElementById("my-element");
window.setInterval(function() {
  dothing(el);
});
```

(Other objects may or may not be passable -- depending on if they can be serialized, but but in general it would be quite difficult.)

Comment: Not to mention when you need to pass an object as argument (a DOM node, a date...).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ah yes! Excellent.  I'll add that.