# JavaScript Recursion with Timing Event (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, recursion, timer, settimeout, pass-by-value

I am trying to build a timer with JavaScript. Here's my function:

```
var t;
function time(num){
    var buf = num;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=buf;
    buf++;
    alert(buf + " " + num); //For troubleshooting
    t=setTimeout("time(buf)",1000);
}
```

If I run time(0), nothing happens to the part with ID="test". *num* always equals 0 and *buf* always equals 1 (from the alert function) every time the function is called.

I'm comfortable with Java and C, and I know this would work in those language. I know JavaScript is also a pass-by-value language, so why doesn't this timer work?

Also, why did nothing happen when I tried (and changed all the *buf* to *num*)

```
t=setTimeout("time(num)",1000);
```

I know there are other ways to create a timer, but I want to know why this method doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: You may think this is recursion, but it actually isn't.  `time()` gets called, it then calls `setTimeout()` and passes a string that will be executed later.  Then, `time()` returns and some time later, `time()` is called again by the timer code.  This isn't technically recursion.  The first call to `time()` has finished before the second one happens.  You're just scheduling the second call for some time in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid passing strings to `setTimeout`.  When you do this the string is more or less executed as an `eval`, which is evil for many reasons.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout) for more information.

Instead, consider passing an anonymous function to `setTimeout`.  This will make solving your problem trivial:

```
t = setTimeout(function() { time(buf); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a string to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated when the time comes. In this case, when the time comes, there's no `buf` variable anymore and the code throws an error.

You should substitute the value yourself.

```
t = setTimeout("time(" + buf + ")",1000);
```

Or, better yet, pass a function instead of string

```
t = setTimeout(function() {
  time(buf);
}, 1000);
```