# setTimeout() doesn't allow me to pass text values

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback)
>   [Is there ever a good reason to pass a string to setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout)

I want to call a function `loadPHPQuote(code)` after 1 second. And want to pass the parameter called **code** which is containing both numbers and text characters. But `setTimeout()` wasn't work if the code contain a character it is OK with only numbers.

Here is my code

```
setTimeout('loadPHPQuote('+code+')',1000);
```

Is there anyone who can help me with this please.....?

Comment: What exactly is `code`? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
setTimeout(function() { loadPHPQuote(code); }, 1000);
```

- When you use quotes, it calls `eval` behind the scene,
- when you need to pass arguments wrap it in a function like above.
- To prevent calling function immediately, don't use `()` in `setTimeout` or `setInterval` directly

Comment: Oh my God its working. I never thought I can go through this. thanks dear so... much now I can proceed from here easily.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to pass strings as parameters to `setTimeout()` (see, e.g., [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval!)). Use an anonymous function instead:

```
setTimeout( function(){ loadPHPQuote( code ); }, 1000 );
```

Comment: If you could provide an explanation as to why it's not recommended, it'd be a better answer :) but nonetheless, +1

Comment: @SiGanteng was just searching for the MDN link ,-)

Comment: @JeevanDammika so you have 2 dears now? :p. Sirko: haha yeah saw that 5 minutes after my comment, can't edit nemore

Comment: @Sirko about MDN :- Thanks for the link it is really worth to read. now I know how to use both these function eval() and setTimeout().

Comment: @SiGanteng : I would like to have dear friends as many as I can not just a 2.

Answer (score 1):

You need you parameter to be in quotes, as it is a string you are passing, e.g.:

```
setTimeout('loadPHPQuote("'+code+'")',1000);
```