# How to set an interval, but then stop it after 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently on my webpage I have a timer that runs a function every 30 seconds:

```
setInterval("someFunction(userId)", 30000);
```

This works fine, but the problem is if 100's of users leave their browser open (say when they go for lunch), it will poll our system and increase the load on our servers for no reason.

How can I stop this timer from running after say 20 minutes?

Comment: Pass functions to `setInterval`, not strings.

Comment: Don't use a string as the first parameter of `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

Comment: @Quentin what's wrong with the string?  It is working fine now?

Comment: @user1361315 Using `eval` in JavaScript is a bad practice.

Comment: See [Is there ever a good reason to pass a string to setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set timeout for 20 minutes to clear the interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    someFunction(userId);
}, 30000);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000 * 60 * 20);
```

Comment: I suggest to incorporate event listeners in the code, because otherwise the code just stops running after 20 minutes, even if the user is actively using the site.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setInterval`, you get a value returned, which is a handle to the running interval.

So the solution is to schedule *another* closure, which will prevent this interval from running:

```
var interval = setInterval("someFunction(userId)", 30000);  
setTimeout(function(){ clearInterval(interval) }, 20 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your interval as a variable.

Set another timer to reset that interval, or set a disable flag for your polling script after 20mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var intervalId= setInterval(function(){
   someFunction(userId);
 }, 30000); 

setTimeout(function(){
   clearInterval(intervalId);
},20*60*1000);
```

`setInterval` returns an intervalId that you can use to pass to `clearInterval` later on.