# JavaScript setTimeout in Object

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to give an object a countdown timer and when the countdown is down it should call a function which removes this object from an array.

```
array = [];

var object = {
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() {
         setTimeout(destroyMe(this),10000);
    }
}

array.push(object);

var destroyMe = function(obj) {
    array.remove(obj);
}
```

I know that there could a problem with the this but the timeout function doesnt work at all not even like this:

```
var object = {
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() {
               setTimeout(console.log("dd"),3000);
            }
}
```

Maybe someone can tell me the issue with my version of the setTimeout.
thx

Comment: `[].remove`? Never heard of it. And you need to do a `array[0].limit()` to initiate the countdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

setTimeout takes a reference to a function. The code you have is calling the function.

This should be changed to:

```
var object = 
{
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() 
    {
        setTimeout(function() { destroyMe(this); }, 10000);
    }
}
```

(You may have issues using `this` in this context, try it!)

```
var object = 
{
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() 
    {
        setTimeout( function() { console.log("dd"); },3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` will be the global object. He needs to use some other variable pointing to the correct object.

Comment: first thing's first, call `array[0].limit();` somewhere.

Comment: I was hoping that the Timout function would call itself after 3 seconds! But it doesnt if i use the code above!

Comment: @user1354743 Are you calling object's `limit` function?

Comment: No I am not....I was hoping after the 10 seconds the it will be called by itself without me calling limit!

Comment: @user1354743 `limit` is a function. What other functions automatically run themselves without the programmer's intervention?

Comment: alright I understand that ...but is there a way that it would work as I wanted it? ... for example: once the object is created the countdown starts and after 3 seconds it will execute the function!???

Comment: @user1354743: Just put the `setTimeout` call *after* the object.

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted! Thx

Comment: 'limit' : setTimeout(destroyMe(this),10000)

Comment: @user1354743 - No, that won't work. You're calling the function, not passing a reference to a function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a *function* to `setTimeout`, not a function call.

```
var object = {
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() {
         setTimeout(function() { 
             destroyMe(this)
         }, 10000);
    }
};
```

As you already know, the `this` probably doesn't do what you are expecting. Replacing `destroyMe(this)` with `console.log("dd")` should result in a behavior that you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` either takes a callback (a function, not a function call with arguments) or code in quotes. However, as noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout), passing a string is only allowed for historical reasons--there aren't any good reasons for doing it in practice.

But, for completeness sake, one way to do what you want is:

```
var object = {
    'name' : 'user',
    'limit' : function() {
               setTimeout('console.log("dd")', 3000);
            }
}
```

Comment: Please do not suggest passing a string. Ever. There is just not a single acceptable reason to do pass a string instead of a function. Besides that he needs `this` to be preserved.

Comment: If mentioning the string passing, you *must* IMO also warn that it's a pretty terrible way to do things.