# Jquery set interval not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The anchors in the span tag should change every 5 seconds but nothing happens.
I've tested that jQuery works in WordPress with `alert("test");` at the top of my js file.

```
    <div class="img_ad"><span><a class="active"><img src="http://www.test.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/client3.png" /></a>
    <a><img src="http://www.test.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/client1.png" /></a>
    <a><img src="http://www.test.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/client2.png" /></a></span><span></span><span></span>
 </div>
```

-

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  function swapImages(){
      var $active = $('.img_ad').find("span:first").find(".active");
      var $next = ($('.img_ad').find("span:first").find('.active').next().length > 0) ? $('.img_ad').find("span:first").find('.active').next() : $('.img_ad').find("span:first").find('a:first');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
      });
    }

     // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);


});
```

This code doesn't work, i put `alert("test");` in the function swapImages() but nothing happens.  I think setInterval is not working.  How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
   swapImages()
},5000);
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the function directly:

```
setInterval(swapImages, 5000);
```

Passing a string is not a recommended way.

- [Is there ever a good reason to pass a string to setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6081560/1420197)

---

Your code doesn't work because `swapImages` is not a global function. Passing a string to `setInterval` -- e..g. `"swapImages()"` -- [requires that the function is globally defined](http://jsfiddle.net/n3rhqf3r/2/) (`window.swapImages = function () { ... }`).

```
(function () {
    function foo() {
        console.log(1);
    }
    setInterval("foo()", 100); // foo is not defined
})();
```

That's why [you have to **pass the real function**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3rhqf3r/) or [an anonymous function that will call your function](http://jsfiddle.net/n3rhqf3r/1/).

For the links from JSFiddle, open the dev tools window (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and go to console.