# why we are using quotes inside a parameter for a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Redirect()
{
    window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
}

document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

1.Here my question is inside settimeout method how can we use a function to call,if we use string literal inside the single quotes i think that is represent to write the exact result like `document.write("hello");`now the result will be as it is inside the string..how javascript can understand that `setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);` 'redirect()' as a method ,instead of writing the it as is..

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function Redirect() {
    window.location="http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
}
document.write("You will be redirected to our main page in 10 seconds!");
setTimeout(Redirect(), 10000);
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2.When i do like this as  `setTimeout(Redirect(), 10000);`,it is not working ...it starts to redirect the page directly instead using that settimeout  it...

Comment: `setTimeout(Redirect, 10000);`, otherwise it will execute immediately, not after the timeout period. Pass the function, let setTmeout run it!

Comment: You are invoking the function,not passing it as reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your code is calling `Redirect()` immediately is because it gets evaluated when `setTimeout` is run.

What you can do to mitigate that is to pass an anonymous function to wrap around the method. Like so: `setTimeout(function(){ Redirect(); }, 10000);`

This link explains why your string `"Redirect()"` is evaluated as you'd expect. In short (taken from the link): String literals are evaluated in the global context, using `eval`.
[WindowTimers.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: True. Although if in the future he wanted to pass an argument to the `Redirect` function, he could just add in the argument instead of writing the anonymous function.

Comment: hmm ya it working,but how the string understands it as a method like ('redirect()')?

Comment: [setTimeout() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) There is a link explaining what setTimeout does. In short, setTimeout runs `eval` on the string in the global context.

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 2):

We have to pass only the function name(without brackets), write like this :

```
setTimeout(Redirect, 10000);
```

It will work.

Comment: hmm ya it working,but how the string understands it as a method like this('redirect()')?

Comment: @RajaRamanTechWorld Refer this, you will understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout

Comment: @RajaRamanTechWorld: [arcane magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 0):

If you write it without quotes: `setTimeout(yourFunction(),1000)` the browser runs that function immediately, because it is a direct call.

If you write it in quotes, the setTimeout-js-method interprets the string and call it after the timeout.

You could write `setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000)`. That works. But consider, that in this case you can't pass any arguments.

To solve that you could write the params in a var which your timeouthandler can read in the moment it runs:

```
yourFunction(){
    alert(param);
} 
var param="Hello";
setTimeout(yourFunction, 1000);
```

Greetings André