# setTimeout() in a for loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

```
list = [1000,2000,3000,4000];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(console.log('Hello'), list[i]);}
```

Why doesn't this code print out 'Hello' after the times in the list?

Comment: you are passing the result of `console.log` to setTimeout`

Comment: Please don't edit your question if that edit makes existing answers obsolete. It would be better to ask a new question instead, but in this case that would also be a duplicate.

Comment: Also, I don't recommend passing a string to setTimeout. There are [many reasons that is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25259001/772035).

Comment: Particularly, you shouldn’t edit your question to _correct_ your code.

Answer (score 3):

this is the right way to do it :

```
list = [1000,2000,3000,4000];
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('Hello')}, list[i]);}
```

because `setTimeout` accepts a callback function not an instruction

Comment: As variant, `setTimeout("console.log('Hello')", list[i]);`

Comment: Using JS bin and it`s saying, don`t use a function in a loop. Should I use a different program.

Comment: Take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `console.log()` *immediately* and passing the return value as the argument to `setTimeout`.

You should be passing a function. The `bind()` method will return a new function that calls `log` with the correct context and the arguments you specify.

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(console, 'Hello'), list[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list = [1000,2000,3000,4000];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { alert(index); }, i * list[i]);
    })(i);
}
```