# Refresh JS function with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function checkDownload(a, b) {
    var number = a;
    var id = b;

    //NOT RELATED CODE....
    setTimeout("checkDownload(number,id)", 5000);
}
checkDownload("test", "test1");
```

So the thing is, at the `setTimeout` an Error comes with (Cannot find variable number).... But why? I only want to refresh the function after 5 seconds with the variable I got before.

Regards

Comment: Duplicate of [*Is there ever a good reason to pass a string to setTimeout?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout)? The question itself mentions the string version using globals...

Answer (score 9):

> So the think is, at the setTimeout an Error comes with (Cannot find variable number).... But why?

Because when you use a string with `setTimeout`, the code in that string is evaluated at global scope. If you don't have *global* `number` and `id` variables, you'll get an error.

Don't use strings with `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, use functions:

```
// On any recent browser, you can include the arguments after the timeout and
// they'll be passed onto the function by the timer mechanism
setTimeout(checkDownload, 5000, number, id);

// On old browsers that didn't do that, use a intermediary function
setTimeout(function() {
    checkDownload(number, id);
}, 5000);
```