# I need a javascript to open url for 30 sec and then open jsp file

Tags: javascript, java, html

I need a javascript which can 1st open a url for rsa authentication and then open the jnlp.jsp file.

I worked on this function so far

```js
function open_win() {
    window.open("http://ppsaccess/");
    setTimeout("window.location.href =\"https://****:8443/jnlp.jsp?port=8443&protocol=https:&serverName=***&commonMaintenanceTool=false\"><img",10000);
}
</script>
```

This what I got

```js
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    window.open("http://ppsaccess/");
}
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href ="https://***:8443/jnlp.jsp?port=8443&protocol=https:&serverName=***&commonMaintenanceTool=false\";
},10000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="PR1" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm just wondering why `php` is tagged when `jsp` is involved?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but please ___[don't call `setTimeout` with a string as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout)___!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the set timeout line to be a closure function:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href ="https://****:8443/jnlp.jsp?port=8443&protocol=https:&serverName=***&commonMaintenanceTool=false\"><img";
},10000);
```

Comment: just tried it <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function open_win() {
    window.open("http://ppsaccess/");
}
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href ="https://***:8443/jnlp.jsp?port=8443&protocol=https:&serverName=****&commonMaintenanceTool=false\";
},10000);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type=button value="PR1" onclick="open_win()">
</form>
</body>

</html>d and it didn't work.

Comment: @Raju435675 Maybe use a fiddle and link to that..very hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: you are escaping the closing `"`