# Text box without button. If you type some letters and push 'Enter', comes after 1 second alert dialog box with text from text box

Tags: javascript, settimeout, alert, enter

I'd like to make a webpage with text box without button. If i type couple of letters and push button 'Enter', comes after 1 second alert dialog box with text from text box. Everything works correct, only that aler dialog box doesn`t come after Enter, but after mouse click.

```html
<!Doctype HTML!>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>6-4</head>
  <script>
 
var keyCode = '';
var naam = '';

window.onload = function () {
  
  var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
  
  document.getElementById('txtInput').addEventListener('blur', function () {
    naam = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;
    
    document.getElementById('txtInput').onkeyup = function (e) {
      keyCode = e.keyCode;
      if (keyCode === 13) {
      }
    };
    setTimeout("alert(naam);", 1000);
  }, false);
};
function stopAlerts() {
  clearInterval(txtNaam);
}
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Type some letters in text box and push 'Enter'</h2>
  <input type="text" id="txtInput" value="" />
  <div id="divResult"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set one event on the textbox, `keydown`, and move the timer into the `true` block of the `if` statement.

**Notes:**

- Your DOCTYPE is wrong. There should only be an exclamation at the
  start of it.
- For your HTML document to be valid, you must add a non-empty `title`
  element in the `head` section. You cannot nest a `head` element
  within anther `head` element.
- If you want your textbox to be empty, there's no need to add
  `value=""`.
- [Passing a string of JavaScript to `setTimeout()` is not advised.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081560/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout)
  Instead pass a function to be executed.
- Instead of placing your `script` in the `head` and then setting up a
  `window.onload` event handler for the code that should run
  automatically when the DOM is ready, move your `script` to just
  before the closing `body` tag and remove the `onload` event handler
  and just execute the code you want run.
- Also, there is no need to scan for the textbox element within the
  event handler for that element. You can just access the textbox
  within the handler with [`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
- [Don't use self-terminating tags.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939538/difference-between-script-src-foo-js-script-and-script-src-foo-js/46939597#46939597)
- Using an `h2` without having an `h1` is semantically incorrect and
  will cause issues for those who rely on assistive technologies. Never
  use an HTML element because of the way the browser styles it by
  default. Styling is CSS' job. If you want some big, bold text and are
  not starting a new section, stay away from heading elements and just
  style the text.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>6-4</title>
  <style>
    h1 { font-size:1.1em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Type some letters in text box and push 'Enter'</h1>
  <input type="text" id="txtInput">
  <div id="divResult"></div>
  
  <script>
    var divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
    document.getElementById('txtInput').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
          setTimeout(function(){ alert(e.target.value); }, 1000);
      }
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI, `keyCode` is deprecated, superseded by `KeyboardEvent.key`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I appreciate that. :-)   I do javascript/jquery course so all those advices are important for me.

Answer (score 1):

This uses Jquery to detect enter key pressed.

**Notes:**

- `<input>` doesn't need a / because it is a self closing tag. For more info on that see [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5).
- You cannot nest 2 `<head>` tags. It has to be `<title>`.
- `<!Doctype html>` can only have 1 `!` at the `<`.
- If you want it to only alert inside the text box change

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(event) {
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if (keycode == '13') {
      alert(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);
   }
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(event) {
   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
   if (keycode == '13') {
      alert(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype Html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    h1 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
    }
  </style>
  <title>6-4</title>
  <script>
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if (keycode == '13') {
        alert(document.getElementById("txtInput").value);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Type some letters in text box and push 'Enter'</h1>
  <input type="text" id="txtInput">
  <div id="divResult"></div>
</body>

</html>
```