# How to check the users connectivity?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a little web-app and want to check the users connectivity before I allow him to submit his data.

```
      function testConnection() {
       var xmlhttp;

       document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "block";

       if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {                        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

       var success = false;

       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         document.getElementById("noConnectivity").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "none";
         success = true;
        }
       }

       connIterator = connIterator + 1;
       xmlhttp.open("GET","testConnection.jsp?i="+connIterator,true); // Dynamic URL to prevent caching
       xmlhttp.send();

       // Wait 10 seconds
       for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // If no success so far, keep waiting
        if(!success) {
         window.setTimeout('1000');
        } else {
         return true;
        }
       }

       // success still isn't true, so we assume a timeout
       document.getElementById("noConnectivity").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "none";
       return false;
      }
```

The problem is that this function always returns false, even if the file is reachable.
When adding an alert before `window.setTimeout('1000');` it works, so I assume the the `setTimeout` does not work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you even create a connectivity check when you're developing an webapp?

Comment: In my case it is quite sure that the user might loose the connection from time to time

Comment: Thats why we've got HTTP status codes ;p

Comment: If the server is not reachable at all, it won't return a statuscode too :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect timeout on an AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) call in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018705/how-to-detect-timeout-on-an-ajax-xmlhttprequest-call-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning before the check is complete. Remember, JavaScript is event-driven. Here is a potential fix (untested):

```
// when connected, call the callback
function testConnection(callback) {
 var xmlhttp;

 document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "block";

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {                        // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "none";
    if (callback) {
      callback(xmlhttp);
    }
  }
 }

 connIterator = connIterator + 1;
 xmlhttp.open("GET","testConnection.jsp?i="+connIterator,true); // Dynamic URL to prevent caching
 xmlhttp.send();
}


document.getElementById("noConnectivity").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("checkingConnectivity").style.display = "none";
testConnection(function() {
  // this code will run when the connection succeeds
  document.getElementById("noConnectivity").style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help! but doesnt this elliminate the possibility that the request just times out?

Comment: In this code `noConnectivity` will remain on the screen until the request succeeds. But you can certainly do various things as the `xmlhttp` object goes through different states.

Comment: thanks! I would tick your answer now, but I found that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018705/how-to-detect-timeout-on-an-ajax-xmlhttprequest-call-in-the-browser does solve my issue too. Do you think I should mark my question as duplicate?

Comment: Treat this question as it's own, since it already has a couple of answers. I'll edit this question to add a link to that other one.

Answer (score 0):

There is `navigator.onLine`. The spec says:

> Returns false if the user agent is definitely offline (disconnected
>   from the network). Returns true if the user agent might be online.
>
> The events online and offline are fired when the value of this
>   attribute changes.
>
> The navigator.onLine attribute must return false if the user agent
>   will not contact the network when the user follows links or when a
>   script requests a remote page (or knows that such an attempt would
>   fail), and must return true otherwise.

The problems it that it's not that reliable as the computer may have a network connection, but no internet access.